# Is it OK to use the average of regression coefficients to generate a curve for missing data?

Tags: regression-coefficients

I am trying to generate a option volatility skew curve for a stock with only a couple of strikes.  Given the lack of sufficient data to generate a curve, I would like instead to fall back on the data I have for other more liquid stocks with many strikes.  In essence I have an equation for a given group of names, say IBM, DELL, HP, MSFT, AAPL where the equation is in the form:
$$
    vol = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+\rm constant
$$
I want to use the above data for a startup tech company that has only traded one strike (I have only one data point).

How can I best use the information from the 5 good names to build a "best guess" 4th order curve for the startup?  Is it simply a matter of averaging the a,b,c,d and constant terms?

Comment: You don't have missing data, AFAICT, you want to *predict* the future volatility of a new study unit from the pattern seen in previous units.

Comment: Agree with gung's comment. Additionally, I would be very worried about extrapolating from such very large established stocks to a startup. I would assume other startups would be a more reasonable comparison and you may also have to allow for some variability between companies (e.g. by having random effects on parameters) to capture at least to some extent that no two companies are going to quite be the same and bring in some additional uncertainty. 5 other companies seems like an extremely small sample for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Statisticians would say that you have at the very least missing not at random ([MNAR](http://handbook.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_1_2_general_principles_for_dealing_with_missing_data.htm)). It's a problem. In your case the reason you don't have strikes is because people have no clue what's the volatility skew. So, you're trying to apply the skew from liquid stock - it's problematic. If it made a sense, then you'd see other strikes on the stock at question. No, you can't do what you're trying to do.